# Python tkinter app crash when trying to run a second time

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `tkinter` app that loads a photo and allows you to do some HSV thresholding.

The app works when running for the first time (as in, called from command line or for the first time in PyCharm). However, when I try to call it again from the same console (in PyCharm) it fails.

Ideally, I would call this app over several images inside another script. Below there's a toy example.

```
# Get a random image
import os
out_image = 'stackoverflow.png'
url = 'https://hanatemplate.com/images/stack-overflow-logo-4.png'
os.system("wget -O {0} {1}".format(out_image, url))


image = "stackoverflow.png"


for i in range(2):
    App(tkinter.Tk(), "HSV app", image_file=image)
```

Again, the for loop works when running the app for the first time. So, somehow, multiple calls are allowed like this, but the app crashes if I do

```
# Run 1st time, fresh console
App(tkinter.Tk(), "HSV app", image_file=image)
# Run for the 2nd time
App(tkinter.Tk(), "HSV app", image_file=image)
```

The error I get is

```
invalid command name "140299000285696update"
    while executing
"140299000285696update"
    ("after" script)
```

So I went to the `update()` function within the app. The image is being captured by `MyVideoCapture` but I pinned down the error to the `create_window(...)` command. I tried to work around it with a `try/except`. This did not prove useful.

```
def update(self):
    # Get a frame from the video source
    frame = self.vid.get_frame()

    # get cursor values
    #self.get_cursor()

    # Get slider values
    self.slider_values()

    # Do image processing
    binarymask = cv2.inRange(frame.copy(), self.HSV_min, self.HSV_max)

    # Resizing
    #frame = cv2.resize(frame, (int(self.vid.width / 2), int(self.vid.height / 2)))
    #binarymask = cv2.resize(binarymask, (int(self.vid.width / 2), int(self.vid.height / 2)))


    self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
    self.binarymask = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(binarymask))

    try:
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 5, image=self.photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)
        self.canvas.create_image(self.vid.width + 5, 5, image=self.binarymask, anchor=tkinter.NW)
    except:
        # try to recapture
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.image_file)

    self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)
```

When the app fails, everything is "loaded" but no images are shown. If I remove the `try`, the app crashes with this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 99, in __init__
  File "<input>", line 142, in update
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2322, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2313, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
TclError: image "pyimage879" doesn't exist
```

Here's the full code of the app.

```
# region App

import Tkinter as tkinter
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time
import tkMessageBox
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np


class App:
    def __init__(self, window, window_title, image_file):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)
        self.image_file = image_file
        # Create pop-up for controls
        self.top = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)

        # open video source (by default this will try to open the computer webcam)
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.image_file)

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=self.vid.width * 2, height=self.vid.height*1.1, borderwidth=0,
                                     background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tkinter.Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        # Capture clicks
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_cursor)

        # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot = tkinter.Button(self.top, text="Snapshot", width=50, command=self.snapshot)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)

        # region Sliders ####

        # H min
        self.H_min_slider = tkinter.Scale(self.top, from_=0, to=255,
                                          orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                                          sliderlength=15, length=200,
                                          label="H_min")
        self.H_min_slider.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True)

        # H max
        self.H_max_slider = tkinter.Scale(self.top, from_=0, to=255,
                                          orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                                          sliderlength=15, length=200,
                                          label="H_max")
        self.H_max_slider.set(255)
        self.H_max_slider.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True, pady=2)

        # S min
        self.S_min_slider = tkinter.Scale(self.top, from_=0, to=255,
                                          orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                                          sliderlength=15, length=200,
                                          label="S_min")
        self.S_min_slider.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True, pady=2)

        # S max
        self.S_max_slider = tkinter.Scale(self.top, from_=0, to=255,
                                          orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                                          sliderlength=15, length=200,
                                          label="S_max")
        self.S_max_slider.set(255)
        self.S_max_slider.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True, pady=2)

        # V min
        self.V_min_slider = tkinter.Scale(self.top, from_=0, to=255,
                                          orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                                          sliderlength=15, length=200,
                                          label="V_min")
        self.V_min_slider.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True, pady=2)

        # V max
        self.V_max_slider = tkinter.Scale(self.top, from_=0, to=255,
                                          orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                                          sliderlength=15, length=200,
                                          label="V_max")
        self.V_max_slider.set(255)
        self.V_max_slider.pack(anchor=tkinter.CENTER, expand=True, pady=2)

        # endregion

        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

        # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
        self.delay = 10
        self.update()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def snapshot(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        frame = self.vid.get_frame()



    def slider_values(self):

        self.HSV_min = (self.H_min_slider.get(), self.S_min_slider.get(), self.V_min_slider.get())
        self.HSV_max = (self.H_max_slider.get(), self.S_max_slider.get(), self.V_max_slider.get())

        return

    def update(self):
        # Get a frame from the video source
        frame = self.vid.get_frame()

        # get cursor values
        #self.get_cursor()

        # Get slider values
        self.slider_values()

        # Do image processing
        binarymask = cv2.inRange(frame.copy(), self.HSV_min, self.HSV_max)

        # Resizing
        #frame = cv2.resize(frame, (int(self.vid.width / 2), int(self.vid.height / 2)))
        #binarymask = cv2.resize(binarymask, (int(self.vid.width / 2), int(self.vid.height / 2)))


        self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
        self.binarymask = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(binarymask))

        #try:
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 5, image=self.photo, anchor=tkinter.NW)
        self.canvas.create_image(self.vid.width + 5, 5, image=self.binarymask, anchor=tkinter.NW)
        #except:
            # try to recapture
            # self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.image_file)

        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)

    def on_closing(self):
        if tkMessageBox.askyesno("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            self.window.destroy()
            time.sleep(1)
            # Force deletion of the video object
            self.vid.__del__()

    def get_cursor(self, event):
        x = self.window.winfo_pointerx()
        y = self.window.winfo_pointery()
        abs_coord_x = self.window.winfo_pointerx() - self.window.winfo_rootx()
        abs_coord_y = self.window.winfo_pointery() - self.window.winfo_rooty()
        print([x,y,abs_coord_x, abs_coord_y])
        return


# This will prevent the user from closing the top window (which stalls the program)
def disable_event():
    pass


class MyVideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, image_file):
        # Open the video source
        self.vid = cv2.imread(image_file, 1)

        # Get video source width and height
        self.width = self.vid.shape[0]
        self.height = self.vid.shape[1]

    def get_frame(self):
        frame = self.vid
        return (cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))  # cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV

    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
            # Try many times to release the camera
            for i in range(0, 10):
                time.sleep(0.05)
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: First thing I can think of is that `TclError: image "pyimage879" doesn't exist` generally pops because you tried to manipulate an image that has been garbage-collected. It's hard to tell, but maybe you should keep a reference on the `PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)` you're passing to `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` in `update`

Comment: This is among the many things that go wrong if you call `Tk()` more than once.  Each call creates an entirely independent Tcl/Tk environment; Tcl objects (including images and variables) will not work in any environment other than the one they were created in - and are generally created by default in the first environment that was instantiated, whether or not that's the one you're curently trying to use.

Comment: @Rightleg "Keep a reference" as in `self.frame = PIL.Image.fromarray(frame)` and then call `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.frame)` ??

Comment: @jasonharper Does this mean that there's no way to "clean/refresh" the environment without closing and reopening the python console? Any workaround to have an equivalent functionality ?

Comment: @stovfl Why not...here https://gist.github.com/matiasandina/51f98f9b42e4a2eef71ed80b44b0da0d